# Left clicking with Visual Basic Scripts

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to get a VBScript to left/right click. I thought there might be a way to using the `WshShell.SendKeys` method, but it didn't include anything that would help me. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack, but you can....

1. right click
2. then go down the menu
3. then hit enter

Here it is :

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys("+{F10}")
WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: that opens the menu and goes down, I need it to click where the mouse currently is.

Comment: Like I said it's a hack, but the first item in every right clicked link menu is the same action as a left click 'open'.

Comment: I finally see what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This Simulates a right click `WshShell.SendKeys("+{F10}")`
I don't know how to simulate a left click though

Answer (score 0):

`WshShell.SendKeys("-{F10}")` to simulate a left click